# get data from multiple tables with some Null value in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables

1. Milksupply(id, date, quantity)
2. Inventory (id,date,  item_id, quantity)
3. Item (id, item_name)

what i want to achieve is:

1.calcualte the total quantity of milk monthly with
items added in inventory on daily basis

there is a relation between inventory and item , but the milksupply table is separate. any one tell me how it is?

Comment: So the ID in 'milksupply' is not related to the one in 'inventory' or 'item'?

Comment: Yes ..there is no id in that related to inventory or item

Answer (score 0):

You can join Milksupply with date

JOIN Milksupply ON Milksupply.date=Inventory.date

(make sure that there are indexes also for dates - otherwise it will be slow)

Then you can make statistics as you need - SUM and GROUP BY some date functions maybe:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html